# Optimization over vectors with Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a problem in vectors $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, where every $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n {y_i}^u {x_i}^{1-u}\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\\ & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 1\\ & \mathbf{a} \leq \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}\\ & \mathbf{c} \leq \mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{d}\end{array}$$

where $u \in (0,1)$ and nonnegative vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{d}$ are given (namely they are **known** and one can choose them freely as long as they satisfy the constraints) such that the following conditions are also satisfied:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i<1,\ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i<1,\quad \mbox{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^n b_i>1,\ \sum_{i=1}^n d_i>1
$$

Can I solve such a problem with Mathematica? I was thinking about using NMaximize or Maximize but I have no experience for optimization over vectors using Mathematica, thats why I have no Mathematica code.

**Addendum:** I think Daniel is right. Therefore I prepared the vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{d}$:

```
u=0.5;
a[i_] := 0.6*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i]
b[i_] := 1.5*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i]
c[i_] := 0.4*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i]
d[i_] := 2*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i]
```

> I am still looking for answers which could work for $n>40$.

Comment: Try setting `n` to some small value (say 2, 3, or 4) and set up the `Maximize` function.  Maybe from trying a few values of `n` you might see a pattern for a general answer.

Comment: Do you want to maximize the above function for $u$ given $x$ and $y$?  Or given $u$ choose the values of $x$ and $y$ that maximize the function?

Comment: @JimBaldwin $u$ is given. one can take it as say $0.5$. The unknowns are $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$  vectors. If I could have written a code for $n=10$, then this code would have also worked for every $n$..

Comment: If $a=c=0$ and $b=d=1$, is the answer for any $u$: $x_i=y_i=1/n$ which results in the maximum always being 1 ?

Comment: @JimBaldwin my best guess is that you are right. Moreover, I think that for any $a=c$ and $b=d$ no matter what they are equal to one would get $x_i=y_i\forall i$. This is probably the most trivial part of the problem. The non trivial part is when a,b,c,d unequal almost everywhere.

Comment: This really needs an explicit example.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau as you suggested, I've prepared an explicit example. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Your example only works for $n\le20$. Since `PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, p], n]` is 0 for $n>20$, your constraints force $x_n$ and $y_n$ to be 0 for $n>20$.

Comment: @CarlWoll Every $20$ will be changed with $40$ in the code. Actually, the parameter of the Binomial would be $n$. Namely, $n=40$ a = Table[0.6*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, 0.3], i], {i, n}];
b = Table[1.5*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, 0.3], i], {i, n}];
c = Table[0.4*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, 0.7], i], {i, n}];
d = Table[2*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, 0.7], i], {i, n}];
X = Array[x, n];

Answer (score 2):

```
u = 0.5;
n = 20
a = Table[0.6*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i], {i, n}];
b = Table[1.5*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i], {i, n}];
c = Table[0.4*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i], {i, n}];
d = Table[2*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i], {i, n}];
X = Array[x, n];
Y = Array[y, n];

FindMaximum[{X^(1 - u).Y^u, 
  Flatten[{ Total[X] == 1 , Total[Y] == 1, 
    MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {a, X, b}], 
    MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {c, Y, d}]}]}  , Flatten[Join[{X, Y}]]]
```

This yields a result (`0.287865`) along with a warning that it is not converged, only a best estimate.

(Note for the given a,b,c,d, n must be a pretty large number )

Comment: Looks good. I guess you posted while I was still writing mine up.

Comment: would it be possible to plot the vectors a, b,c ,d and the vectors x, y together? we can then compare different answers..

Comment: what do you mean by $n$ must be a pretty large number? it is given as $20$ already. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just tried to change every $20$ with $50$ in your code and in this case. the solution does not satisfy the constraints.

Comment: sorry to be vague. I meant `n` can not be like 2 or 3. (due to Sum b,d >1 requirement)  Beyond about 20 does you no good either because `a,b,c,d` all go to zero. You should get a solution but the extra terms must be zero.

Comment: I am able to get a solution up to $n=34$ and above that the program gives strange results.. For me actually the higher the better. 100 would be great.

Comment: I run with `n=100` and get an answer.  as expected all x[i],y[i] for i>20 are zero since the associated `a[i],b[i],c[i],d[i]` are all zero. Or are you changing the `a,b,c,d` ?

Comment: Yes sure. $n$ will change to $100$ everywhere including the vectors $a,b,c,d$. Otherwise the solution is still over $20$ but with $80$ zeros.

Comment: I mean, every $20$ in $a,b,c,d$ should also be replaced by $100$. Actually by $n$, so that changing $n$ will change the sizes of all vectors to $100$.

Answer (score 2):

For the example provided one might proceed as follows.

```
u = 1/2;
a[i_] := 0.6*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i]
b[i_] := 1.5*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i]
c[i_] := 0.4*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i]
d[i_] := 2*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i]
n = 14;
```

Check the constraints on the totals.

```
In[415]:= Map[Total, {Array[a, n], Array[b, n], Array[c, n], 
  Array[d, n]}]

(* Out[415]= {0.599495482389, 1.49873870597, 0.233451668207, \
1.16725834104} *)
```

Create the `x` and `y` vectors and the set of constraints.

```
xvec = Array[x, n];
yvec = Array[y, n];
c1 = {Total[xvec] >= 1, Total[yvec] >= 1};
c2 = Thread[Array[a, n] <= xvec <= Array[b, n]];
c3 = Thread[Array[c, n] <= yvec <= Array[d, n]];
obj = xvec^u.yvec^(1 - u);
constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3];
vars = Join[xvec, yvec];
```

Notice that I constrain the `x` and `y` sums to be >= unity rather than strictly equal. This is to work around a problem `NMinimize` seems to have with imposing the equality constraint and still finding viable initial search points. Alternatively one can use `FindMinimum` and avoid the issue. Notice that >= suffices because any "minimum" value found that satisfies the strong inequality can be further reduced by making it satisfy the equality instead.

Now we minimize.

```
{min, vals} = NMinimize[{obj, constraints}, regions]

(* Out[600]= {0.113052286045, {x[1] -> 0.0102589870128, 
  x[2] -> 0.0417687898593, x[3] -> 0.107405488744, 
  x[4] -> 0.195631440342, x[5] -> 0.268294549424, 
  x[6] -> 0.141472396852, x[7] -> 0.0985572027817, 
  x[8] -> 0.0686380474937, x[9] -> 0.0392217407402, 
  x[10] -> 0.0184902491202, x[11] -> 0.00720399313413, 
  x[12] -> 0.00231556920486, x[13] -> 0.000610699578119, 
  x[14] -> 0.000130864199554, y[1] -> 6.50982441109*10^-10, 
  y[2] -> 1.44278086865*10^-8, y[3] -> 2.01986175439*10^-7, 
  y[4] -> 2.00302480394*10^-6, y[5] -> 0.0000149559109898, 
  y[6] -> 0.0000872428055708, y[7] -> 0.000407133069209, 
  y[8] -> 0.00154371284591, y[9] -> 0.00480266214711, 
  y[10] -> 0.012326832933, y[11] -> 0.0402198296988, 
  y[12] -> 0.228793477986, y[13] -> 0.328523969226, 
  y[14] -> 0.383277964372}} *)
```

Check constraints:

```
{c1, c2, c3} /. vals

(* Out[601]= {{True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
  True, True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, 
  True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}} *)
```

`FindMinimum` gives a comparable result.

```
{min, vals} = FindMinimum[{obj, constraints}, vars]

(* Out[602]= {0.113052279616, {x[1] -> 0.0102590056662, 
  x[2] -> 0.0417688087857, x[3] -> 0.107405508307, 
  x[4] -> 0.19563146156, x[5] -> 0.268294575854, 
  x[6] -> 0.141472291161, x[7] -> 0.0985571911308, 
  x[8] -> 0.068638043823, x[9] -> 0.0392217393274, 
  x[10] -> 0.0184902485401, x[11] -> 0.00720399293769, 
  x[12] -> 0.00231556915854, x[13] -> 0.000610699558297, 
  x[14] -> 0.000130864191064, y[1] -> 6.50866427519*10^-10, 
  y[2] -> 1.4427539019*10^-8, y[3] -> 2.01985546167*10^-7, 
  y[4] -> 2.00302333266*10^-6, y[5] -> 0.0000149559075502, 
  y[6] -> 0.0000872427940428, y[7] -> 0.000407133038865, 
  y[8] -> 0.00154371277236, y[9] -> 0.00480266195846, 
  y[10] -> 0.0123268323601, y[11] -> 0.0402198257305, 
  y[12] -> 0.22879347941, y[13] -> 0.328523970434, 
  y[14] -> 0.383277965507}} *)
```

--- edit ---

Here is the `n=20` case. I use equality constraints and `FindMaximum`.

```
u = 1/2;
a[i_] := 0.6*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i]
b[i_] := 1.5*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i]
c[i_] := 0.4*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i]
d[i_] := 2*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i]

n = 20;
Map[Total, {Array[a, n], Array[b, n], Array[c, n], Array[d, n]}]

(* Out[678]= {0.599521246402, 1.49880311601, 0.399999999986, \
1.99999999993} *)

xvec = Array[x, n];
yvec = Array[y, n];
c1 = {Total[xvec] == 1, Total[yvec] == 1};
c2 = Thread[Array[a, n] <= xvec <= Array[b, n]];
c3 = Thread[Array[c, n] <= yvec <= Array[d, n]];
obj = xvec^u.yvec^(1 - u);
constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3];
vars = Join[xvec, yvec];

{min, vals} = FindMaximum[{obj, constraints}, vars]

(* Out[688]= {0.287179170249, {x[1] -> 0.00420039062101, 
  x[2] -> 0.0168068363863, x[3] -> 0.0430675097985, 
  x[4] -> 0.0783747301246, x[5] -> 0.107512002157, 
  x[6] -> 0.162230688536, x[7] -> 0.246265726493, 
  x[8] -> 0.17156411577, x[9] -> 0.0980431454055, 
  x[10] -> 0.0462211272314, x[11] -> 0.0180081125686, 
  x[12] -> 0.00578813622943, x[13] -> 0.00152640343632, 
  x[14] -> 0.000326847202309, x[15] -> 0.0000559562031744, 
  x[16] -> 7.46270969759*10^-6, x[17] -> 7.43504383666*10^-7, 
  x[18] -> 5.41032712888*10^-8, x[19] -> 2.4407490807*10^-9, 
  x[20] -> 5.2301766015*10^-11, y[1] -> 3.2543321076*10^-9, 
  y[2] -> 7.21376950518*10^-8, y[3] -> 9.96710077075*10^-7, 
  y[4] -> 9.96943298*10^-6, y[5] -> 0.000074658665243, 
  y[6] -> 0.000435965674377, y[7] -> 0.00203522075526, 
  y[8] -> 0.00771750424298, y[9] -> 0.0240107719009, 
  y[10] -> 0.0616279225931, y[11] -> 0.130722583872, 
  y[12] -> 0.228736998482, y[13] -> 0.30013881215, 
  y[14] -> 0.0774548114721, y[15] -> 0.0716601191227, 
  y[16] -> 0.0522522505167, y[17] -> 0.0287165994173, 
  y[18] -> 0.0112102849437, y[19] -> 0.0028066714826, 
  y[20] -> 0.000387777172855}} *)

In[691]:= Map[Total, {xvec, yvec} /. vals]

(* Out[691]= {0.999999990973, 0.999999993999} *)
```

Also works fine with `FindMinimum`.

--- end edit ---

Comment: would it be possible to plot the vectors a, b,c ,d and the vectors x, y together? we can then compare different answers.

Comment: the value of $n$ must be $20$. it is actually the length of the vectors $a,b,c,d$ as well as $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Where was it specified that `n=20`? I missed this detail.

Comment: $n$ is the length of the vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. and these vectors are bounded by $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c},\mathbf{d}$, which also have the same length. In the question their sum runs from $1$ to $n$ (see the $4$ constraints just before the end of the question), implying that their lengths are also $n$. In the given example, $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c},\mathbf{d}$ have length $20$, so are $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. I am sorry if It was not clear enough in the question.

Comment: It seems that the code does not work when $n=20$)

Comment: Odd. It worked fine for me. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Try $n=40$.

Comment: Hard problem. Maximizing over a non-convex function space (l_1/2 in this case) is not easy. Might try doing same over l_1, that is, get rid of the `u` and `1-u` exponents, take result as an initial point, use that for the actual problem.

Comment: the objective function is concave for every $u\in[0,1]$ and if Mathematica would not be able to solve this problem, whoelse would be? it is just a kind of optimization over only $50$ variables. their sum will be $1$, optimization will be done in some range and the objective function is just $x^{u}y^{1-u}$..

Comment: There are three responses with a total of two upvotes (one of which was mine). No response has been accepted. The actual problem is at best poorly elaborated and seems to keep changing, with no indication of what, if anything, has been tried by the poster. And now it is turning into a question about different programs, which is definitely outside the scope of this forum. I am of the opinion that this belongs on a different site.

Comment: nothing has changed. the question is the same question. did I edit it? No. Is there any answer which can address the question fully? No. I mean the best answer can solve it for $n=35$ at max. I dont really understand what we are discussing. The first answer which works "properly" will immediately be accepted. Of course you would get upvote, and got one. Thanks for the answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something but not sure the result is right

```
n = 2;
varx = Array[x, n];
vary = Array[y, n];
contsX = And @@ (a < # < b & /@ varx);
contsY = And @@ (c < # < d & /@ vary);
u = 0.4; a = 0; b = 1; c = 0; d = 1;
func = Sum[y[i]^u x[i]^(1 - u), {i, n}];
NMaximize[{func,  Sum[x[i], {i, n}] == 1 && Sum[y[i], {i, n}] == 1 && contsX &&    contsY}, Join[varx, vary]]
```

**EDITED:**

```
varx = Array[x, n];
vary = Array[y, n];
constX = And @@ MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {a, varx, b}];
constY = And @@ MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {c, vary, d}];
func = Total[y[#]^u x[#]^(1 - u) & /@ Range@n]
FindMaximum[{func,   Total@varx == 1 && Total@vary == 1 && contsX && contsY},  Join[varx, vary]]
```

Comment: I provided an example in the question. $a = 0; b = 1; c = 0; d = 1$ is the trivial case.