# Solving a Convex Optimization Problem Using Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following convex optimization problem:
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize}_{{f,g}} & \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} g^u{f}^{1-u}\mathrm{d}\mu\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \mathrm{d}\mu= 1,\quad \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} g\mathrm{d}\mu =1 \\  & f_L \leq {f} \leq f_U\\ & g_L \leq g \leq g_U\end{array}$$
where $u\in(0,1) $ and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_L \mathrm{d}\mu< 1,\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_L \mathrm{d}\mu< 1$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_U \mathrm{d}\mu> 1,\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_U \mathrm{d}\mu> 1$$
Here, $f$ and $g$ are distinct density functions, $f_L,f_U,g_L,g_U$ are some known positive functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

I am looking for a code for this case:

$$f_L=0.8*f_{\mathcal{N}(-1,1)}$$
$$f_U=2*f_{\mathcal{N}(-1,1)}$$
$$g_L=0.8*f_{\mathcal{N}(1,1)}$$
$$g_U=2*f_{\mathcal{N}(1,1)}$$

and here its mathematica code:

```
fL[y_] := 0.8*PDF[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], y]
fU[y_] := 2*PDF[NormalDistribution[-1, 1], y]
gL[y_] := 0.8*PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y]
gU[y_] := 2*PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y]
```

I asked the same question for any programming language [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387155/solving-a-convex-optimization-problem-using-a-any-programming-language). It seems Rahul has an answer, which he wants to keep for himself. That's why I decided to ask the same question here.

> I am not interested in a symbolic solution. Discretization of the densities is all fine.

Here, you can also see a possible solution for the [discrete case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145191/optimization-over-vectors-with-mathematica). I am also posting the working code for the discrete case here:

```
u = 0.5;
n = 20
a = Table[0.6*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i], {i, n}];
b = Table[1.5*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.3], i], {i, n}];
c = Table[0.4*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i], {i, n}];
d = Table[2*PDF[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.7], i], {i, n}];
X = Array[x, n];
Y = Array[y, n];

FindMaximum[{X^(1 - u).Y^u, 
  Flatten[{ Total[X] == 1 , Total[Y] == 1, 
    MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {a, X, b}], 
    MapThread[#1 <= #2 <= #3 &, {c, Y, d}]}]}  , Flatten[Join[{X, Y}]]]
```

Comment: You are not looking for a discrete solution, right?

Comment: In this question, I am looking for a solution for the continuous case. The code for the discrete case is just to provide some ideas.

Comment: Rahul mentions _quadrature points_ so I guess he did not solve this problem in the continuous case. I have never done functional optimisation with MMA before and I am not sure if MMA can solve your problem symbolically, but have you checked the package [`VariationalMethods`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/guide/VariationalMethodsPackage.html)?

Comment: @anderstood no. he should have a solution for the continuous case, for which we also need sampling and interpolation. Check out the question for the discrete case. The best answer works only for $35$ samples.

Comment: @anderstood No I dont know anything about that package. I also dont need an almost perfect solution with symbolic computation. It is completely fine to discretize the density functions, lets say with $100$ points, and then to apply the constraints for the interpolated functions $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Trapezoidal rule**

Here is a function that approximates an integral using the trapezoidal rule:

```
trapezoidalIntegrate[expr_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, n_] := Dot[ 
    Table[expr, {x, Subdivide[x0, x1, n]}],
    ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, n-1],1,1/2](x1-x0)/n
]
```

For example:

```
trapezoidalIntegrate[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, 100] //N
NIntegrate[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

> 2.6668
>
> 2.66667

*If your version of Mathematica doesn't have [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide), you can use:*

```
Subdivide[x0_, x1_, n_] := x0 + Range[0,n] (x1-x0)/n
```

**Discretization**

Using `trapezoidalIntegrate` we can discretize the optimization problem. First, the inputs:

```
fL[y_]:=0.8*PDF[NormalDistribution[-1,1],y]
fU[y_]:=2.*PDF[NormalDistribution[-1,1],y]
gL[y_]:=0.8*PDF[NormalDistribution[1,1],y]
gU[y_]:=2.*PDF[NormalDistribution[1,1],y]
```

I will discretize the range $(-8, 8)$ over 101 points, since that is sufficient to get integrals of `fL`, `fU`, `gL` and `gU` right:

```
trapezoidalIntegrate[fL[x], {x, -8, 8}, 100]
trapezoidalIntegrate[fU[x], {x, -8, 8}, 100]
trapezoidalIntegrate[gL[x], {x, -8, 8}, 100]
trapezoidalIntegrate[gU[x], {x, -8, 8}, 100]
```

> 0.8
>
> 2.
>
> 0.8
>
> 2.

**FindMaximum**

Now, we just need to construct the [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum) expression to evaluate:

```
u = .8;
n = 100;
xi = Subdivide[-8, 8, n];
optimum = FindMaximum[
    Evaluate @ {
        trapezoidalIntegrate[f[x]^u g[x]^(1-u), {x, -8, 8}, n],
        trapezoidalIntegrate[f[x], {x, -8, 8}, n] == 1,
        trapezoidalIntegrate[g[x], {x, -8, 8}, n] == 1,
        And @@ Table[fL[x] < f[x] < fU[x], {x, xi}],
        And @@ Table[gL[x] < g[x] < gU[x], {x, xi}]
    },
    Evaluate @ Join[
        Table[f[x], {x, xi}],
        Table[g[x], {x, xi}]
    ]
];
optimum[[1]]
```

> 0.853142

And plots of `f[x]` and `g[x]` along with the upper and lower bounds:

```
Show[
    Plot[{fL[x], fU[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, PlotRange->All],
    ListLinePlot[Thread[{xi, Table[f[x], {x, xi}]}] /. optimum[[2]], PlotStyle->Green]
]

Show[
    Plot[{gL[x], gU[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, PlotRange->All],
    ListLinePlot[Thread[{xi, Table[g[x], {x, xi}]}] /. optimum[[2]], PlotStyle->Green]
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems so nice.

Comment: The choice of using the trapezoidal rule is quite fortuitous. It is well-known (see e.g. [this](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100024786), [this](https://doi.org/10.2307/2695765) or [this](https://doi.org/10.1137/130932132)) that the trapezoidal rule is able to give high accuracy for Gaussian-type integrals.

Comment: I just had the chance to run it on my computer. I have a little problem. trapezoidalIntegrate[fL[x], {x, -8, 8}, 100] doesnt work in my computer. Which version of mathematica do you use? I have only 9 and 10.

Comment: What does it return? Did you evaluate the function definition?

Comment: @CarlWoll I just saw your comment by luck. I got this: Table::iterb: Iterator {x,xi} does not have appropriate bounds. >> Table[x^2, {x, xi}].{0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,

Comment: @CarlWoll 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
  0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01}

Comment: @CarlWoll after evaluating your definition and the example with  trapezoidalIntegrate[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, 100] //N
NIntegrate[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören See update.

Comment: @CarlWoll I just run the code. It works not but it says the following: FindMaximum::eit: The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of 4.806217383937354`*^-6 in 500 iterations. The best estimated solution, with feasibility residual, KKT residual, or complementary residual of {\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}, is returned. >>

Comment: @CarlWoll the Plots are also not correct.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören It looks like the `FindMaximum` algorithm works better in M11 than M10. You could try using a smaller range, say $(-5, 5)$ and a smaller discretization, say $n=10$, and then M9/M10 will produce a result, albeit with a warning. Or, you can choose a different integral discretization, one that has more points where the functions are significantly different from 0.

Comment: @CarlWoll it is working very well now. Before accepting, I have one more question and one little request if you may want of course. Question: is there any way to obtain the values of Lagrangian multipliers corresponding to the constraints? Request: Is there any way to make the problem for the discete case work for more than $40$ points? That question is still open becase it doesnt cover anything more than $40$. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145191/optimization-over-vectors-with-mathematica

Comment: @CarlWoll I think it will be better if I ask it as a separate question.. It seems it is not possible for me to get the Lagrangian parameters.